# Seeking Sources on Living Piously in a Secular World

Tags: repentance-teshuvah, modern-times, orthodox, secular-culture

In today's society, where secular influence is prevalent, many individuals are navigating the balance between religious observance and worldly engagements. This leads to the question: How does traditional Jewish thought guide those who are immersed in secular environments but seek a deeper connection to their Orthodox roots?

I'm specifically interested in foundational Jewish texts that discuss strategies to cultivate piety and righteousness in the face of secularism. While I'm familiar with the Sefer Hasidim's perspective on piety, are there other primary Jewish texts that shed light on this?

For instance, if we were to consider a hypothetical scenario where a man, isolated on a planet with no Jewish community, only had access to foundational Jewish texts, which ones would best guide him towards righteous living?

Comment: Avot 1:6 comes to mind. And just to emphasize on the detail about judging favorably, that applies to yourself as well. https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.6?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi

Comment: Of course I am apart of this unrighteousness too. I am disgusted with my self and also my arrogance and pride. I am nothing and unrighteous. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Avot 2:13 "Rabbi Shimon said: Be careful with the reading of Shema and the prayer, And when you pray, do not make your prayer something automatic, but a plea for compassion before God, for it is said: “for He is gracious and compassionate, slow to anger, abounding in kindness, and renouncing punishment” ( from Joel 2:13); And be not wicked in your own esteem."

Comment: I now understand why the Sanhedrin would whip, execute and stone people.

Comment: According to Rav Moshe Feinstein executions were exceedingly rare. Like once in 70 years.

Comment: Doing a post-mortem mid-surgery is medical malpractice. Focus on how you can improve and worry about the past when it's in the past.

Comment: Please, PLEASE: You need to talk to a competent rabbi and most likely a mental-health professional. The thought patterns you are describing here are not healthy ones, nor spiritually-productive. If you're thinking about self harm, please dial 998 (in the US). Now.

Comment: To quote Rabbi Yitzchak Breitowitz addressing a group of those not raised Orthodox: "G-d could have decided your soul should have been born into an ultra-Orthodox family in an enclave in Israel; yet G-d chose for you to have been born into a less-affiliated family in, say, Nebraska. There was a reason for that, and you should not be ashamed of it."

Comment: It appears from the tags on your question that you are not Jewish. Your first step would be to throughouly study the 7 laws of Bnei Noah. Start your journey there and see where it takes you.

Comment: I need to convert ASAP but I am beyond simply readkng the 7 laws of Noah which is very elementary. Like with anything I can expand upon these laws greatly.

Comment: I noticed the tag: conversion-to-Judaism. Non-Jews do not need to convert to Judaism, in order to live life as God has made them. All they need to do, is to **meticulously** follow the God-given Noahide Code and its **corollaries**. That in itself can be a lifelong career! If a person wants to improve their character, they can study various self-help books that can help a person work on themselves.

Comment: @IsraelReader well IDC TBH. I wish to convert and I've been engaging in Torah study, learning Hebrew and various other religious Jewish holy books. I'm not even converting for you or the community but for my self given it to be the most rational choice of action given my interests and life.  I can't discuss the subjects I'm interested in with other secular none Jews and self help books aren't anywhere near the level of torah study so.... That's going to happen

Comment: It'd be very weird for me to literally pray, wear Tzitzit, teffilin, be shomer shabbos, mitzvot, kishrout, wear kippah, etc. Etc. And just hardcore concentrate on the 7 laws of Noah.... IDT that's even possible or suggested unless I start incorporating secular Philosophy into it like Kant's, metaphysics, classics, etc. Etc.

Comment: Conversion to Judaism is an extremely monumental task and should not be done lightly. Once done, conversion can't be reversed, and if it isn't a good match for you, it will have an adverse effect on you, for the rest of your life. If you want to become a better person, you still don't need to convert to Judaism. You can learn much from good teachers, and change the negative environment that you live in.

Comment: If you've been observing Jewish practices and customs, and aren't satisfied, it might be due to the fact that you're doing things that you aren't obligated to, and you're ignoring the things that a Noahide *must* do. For example, one of the Noahide commandments is the prohibition of murder. A corollary of that, would be embarrassing someone to the extent that they feel that you've "killed" them, or that they're so embarrassed that they wish that they were dead. The list goes on and on and is beyond the scope of this discussion. Perhaps you can create a new question about these corollaries.

Comment: CAN I edit this question so that it can be re-opened? @IsraelReader

Comment: I have recently been introduced to this amazing work by the Piaseczno Rebbe by @Dov. It is incredible, I can't get enough of it, and feel that it will answer a lot of your questions: https://www.sefaria.org/Hakhsharat_HaAvrekhim.1?ven=The_preparation_of_the_Avreichim,_translated_and_Annotated_by_Betzalel_Edwards,_2022&lang=bi&with=Navigation&lang2=en. You can also buy it on Amazon: [Jewish Spiritual Growth: The Step-by-Step Guide of a Hasidic Master](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/1536982261?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details) (that's UK link, but it's also available in US). Convert first.

Comment: thannks lol ill buy it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Repentance is the biggest cleanser of the soul; and there is no sin that can't be forgiven, if a person truly repents.

The first step of repentance; is regret, which you've amply expressed.

The second step of repentance; is to have a firm conviction to disassociate yourself from the sins of the past.

That involves making important life changes that will help you overcome the negative influences of your current situation. Speak to a spiritual advisor that you're comfortable with, who will be able to guide you on your personal path.

By disassociating yourself from the sins of the past, and your sinful environment, you demonstrate the seriousness of your repentance, and cement your future performance, which will hopefully be something that you will be proud of yourself, and God will be proud of you!

Comment: Thank you. I must read more on teshuva

Comment: I revised the question so please reopen it.

Comment: @naarter Sorry, but I didn't vote to close the question, and I'm not on the review board to reopen it.

Answer (score 6):

Neither were Abraham, the holy matriarchs, Josef, Jethro, and even Mosses brought up in the best of surroundings, and the Midrash even says that Abraham worshiped idols in his youth, yet heaven  forbid to say that they were at fault, and according to the Halacha, someone who sinned unknowingly because of the way he was brought up, need not even offer a sacrifice to atone for it, being that he did so unknowingly!

The Talmud says that one can become righteous, and atone for anything and everything in an instant - just by opening your heart like the size of a “needle’s tip”, i.e. the smallest amount - and there are numerous stories in the Talmud of people who earned a share in the world to come in one moment!

Comment: I revised the question so please re-open it.